# detect closed eyes after it closed 3 seconds

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect closed eyes after it closed 3 seconds using openCV in python . But when I used time.sleep(1) to count time, the entire program is stopped .
But the program must be run continuously to dectect close eyes. 
I think that can be used thread in python

```
 def get_frame(self):

    success, image = self.video.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.3,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )



    while True:
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)

            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            eyes = eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            if eyes is not():
                for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
                    cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex -10 ,ey - 10),(ex+ew + 10,ey+eh + 10),(0,255,0),2)
                    twoeyes = twoeyesCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
                    checkyeys = 0
                    if twoeyes is not():
                        for (exx,eyy,eww,ehh) in twoeyes:
                            checkyeys = 0
                            led.write(1)
                            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(exx-5 ,eyy -5  ),(exx+eww -5,eyy+ehh -5 ),(0,0, 255),2)
                    else:
                        #when eyes close
                        print "------------------------------------"
                        for i in xrange(10):
                            time.sleep(1)
                            if(i % 3 == 0){
                                #eyes close in 3 seconds
                                print "Warning"
                            }
                            print i
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        self.string = jpeg.tostring()
        self._image = image
        return jpeg.tostring()
```

Thank for helping !!!

Comment: Did you recognize any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
if(i % 3 == 0){
   #eyes close in 3 seconds
   print "Warning"
}
```

to

```
if i % 3 == 0:
   #eyes close in 3 seconds
   print "Warning"
```

Comment: But the program was stopped because  time.sleep(1)

Comment: Is it still stopping (after the syntax correction)? Does it show any message?

Comment: Did you include a `import time` statement?

Comment: Here are libraries I have import: 
import cv2
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import os
import mraa
from datetime import datetime
import thread

Comment: Is it still stopping (after the syntax correction)? Does it show any message?

Comment: No messages , but the program videostream to detect eyes was stoped. It should run continuously.

Comment: Try to comment/deactivate the `time.sleep` statement. Will it still stop?

Comment: it runs normally when I comment time.sleep

Comment: Have you checked that the indentation of the `time.sleep` line is correct (spaces vs tabs)? What will happen if you call `time.sleep` at some other place in your code, e.g. right after `def get_frame(self):`?

Comment: The program has been stopped, but it was not an error. I checked the space and tab.The problem here is that I call time.sleep in the constructor videostream, and time.sleep make videostream stop.

Comment: Do you know how to count 3 seconds not using time.sleep ?

Comment: You can try it with `cv2.waitKey(3000)`

Comment: It's work for me. 
I just thought of a good way. When eyes closed I put a variable start_time = time.time () and then if open eyes, I get a = time.time () - start_time.
If a> 3, the eye has closed more than 3 seconds.